# Gateway to mask an API end point

Tags: java, php, spring, api, swagger

**That is the purpose, I have details about a commercial API and a white label on it.**

> After by it, I want to resell it to the user of my website.

What is the best way to make redirection of an API to another with same request, parameters, credentials and response back.

*Is there online service to do it ?
Or a technical example using Java spring or php ?*

```
EXAMPLE :

 1. POST, to http://www.commercialapi.com/product/save
{'name': 'customerName', 'nick': 'customerNick'}

 2. DELETE, to http://www.commercialapi.com/product/delete
{'id': 'customerId'}

transform to : 

 1. POST, to http://www.myapi.com/product/save
{'name': 'customerName', 'nick': 'customerNick'}

 2. DELETE, to http://www.myapi.com/product/delete
{'id': 'customerId'}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think Nginx is good solution for this task. You need set Nginx proxy up on your domain.

Try using the [nginx reverse proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)

An example Nginx server for your task would be:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myapi.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://www.commercialapi.com;
        proxy_redirect  http://www.commercialapi.com/ /;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;

        # Your can customize headers as well.
        proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same type of solution with HAProxy.  You should consider injecting your customer ids as headers to the downstream service.

Comment: Thanks for your helps.
I will try it, it looks clear.

I think the first url should be :
proxy_pass      http://www.myapi.com.

It is possible with apache ??

Comment: Dassi, first url should be http://www.commercialapi.com, i am sure. Apache is too monstrous for using only as a proxy... Nginx - is good practice for proxy and allows you create access control logic for proxy using Lua script (directive access_by_lua).